# OpenGL memory leak on Nvidia card

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia

I'm programming a multi-window application with two threads. First is render thread and the second is GUI. There is only one OpenGL context on render thread.
On Intel cards everything is correct, but on Nvidia there is huge memory leak when I create and close window.

Render:

```
mWindowsCriticalSection.enter();

for (auto window : mWindows)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(window.second->getHdc(), mContext);
    //only swap buffers 
    SwapBuffers(window.second->getHdc());
     wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
}

mWindowsCriticalSection.leave();
```

Window creation:

```
mHwnd = CreateWindow(
          WINDOW_CLASS, mTitle.c_str(),
          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
          400, 400,
          400, 400, NULL, NULL,
          GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL
        );

SetWindowLong(mHwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (long)this);
mHdc = GetDC(mHwnd);
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
int pixelFormat = Renderer::getInstance().getPixelFormat();
DescribePixelFormat(mHdc, pixelFormat, sizeof(pfd), &pfd);
SetPixelFormat(mHdc, pixelFormat, &pfd);
WindowsContainer::getInstance().addWindow(shared_from_this());
```

In WM_DESTROY:

```
ReleaseDC(mHwnd, mHdc);
```

This memory leak causes DrvPresentBuffers crash after 20-30 creations and destroys of window.

Any ideas?

Comment: I notice you're using shared_ptr.  It's possible to leak things with circular references.  From the code you present that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Also noticed this: for (auto window : mWindows).  Is mWindows a container of shared_ptr?  To check references put a breakpoint in the destructor and see if it gets called.

Comment: It is not possible. It works perfect on Intel card without memory leaks.

Comment: Do you really need a critical section around your buffer swaps? That's going to create unstable framerate and worse still, if the swap operation blocks, potential deadlocks. The `wglMakeCurrent (...)` function uses thread-local storage for context management, you don't really have any source of contention going on.

Comment: The more pressing issue, however, is that `ReleaseDC (...)` needs to be called from the same thread that called `Get*DC (...)` for similar reasons. It's entirely possible you're calling it from the wrong thread.

Comment: I need critical section because addWindow is called from other thread and synchronization is for mWindows. DC was released, the return value from ReleaseDC is 1. Memory leak is on wglMakeCurrent when i use nvidia card.